# How to get the next and previous record using slug in laravel

Tags: laravel, blogs, slug

I am trying to get the previous and next record in a project (like a blog post). I have not been able to get the id related to the slug of each project.

Could I do it in the same query in my projectController?

I can assign and get the slug of each project, which is created from the title.

```
::ProjectController


    public function single($slug){
       
        $project = Project::with('tools', 'categories')->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        $prev = Project::where('id', '<', $project->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
        $next = Project::where('id', '>', $project->id)->orderBy('id')->first();
        return view('project-single',compact('project',$project))
                    ->with('prev',$prev)
                    ->with('next',$next);
    }
```

```
::SingleProject.blade.php

 @if($prev ==! null)
                <a href="{{ route('project.single', ['project' => $prev]) }}" class="animate">

                  <i class="las la-long-arrow-alt-left"></i>Anterior
                </a> 
                @endif
```

```
::Route

Route::get('/proyectos/{slug}', 'ProjectController@single')->name('project.single');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$project = Project::with('tools', 'categories')->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
 

$more = Project::whereIn('id', [$project->id - 1, $project->id + 1])->get();
$prev = $more->where('id', '<', $project->id)->first();
$next = $more->where('id', '>', $project->id)->first();
```

Comment: what if there are gaps in the ids?

Comment: When i click on next or prev the url is project/1, project/2. and this returns 404. and it should be project/some-slug-of-project

Comment: @Kataldo that is what happens when you pass a model as the route parameter when using the `route` helper, by default it uses the 'id' ... either explicitly pass the slug or you need to adjust the `getRouteKeyName` method to return 'slug' ... which will also make it use that field for Implicit Route Model Binding

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem:

```
::projectController

 public function single($slug){
        $project = Project::with('tools', 'categories')->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        $next = Project::where('id', '>', $project->id)->min('id');
        $prev = Project::where('id', '<', $project->id)->max('id');
        
        return view('project-single',compact('project',$project))
                    ->with('prev',Project::find($prev))
                    ->with('next',Project::find($next));
    }
```

```
:::view

 @if($prev ==! null)
                <a href="{{ route('project.single', ['slug' => $prev->slug]) }}" class="animate">

                  <i class="las la-long-arrow-alt-left"></i>Anterior
                </a> 
                @endif
```